# Playback historical data Akka Stream

Tags: scala, akka-stream

Is it possible to emit data according to a defined clock with Akka Streams?  Or do they just emit (ignoring backpressure) as fast as their data arrive?  I'm particularly wondering if it's possible to playback historical data with a "mocked" clock, somehow using `Source.tick` perhaps.

Comment: What have you already tried by yourself?

Comment: I've built other versions of this system before, just not with a streaming framework.  With streaming it seems like the clock should be a `Source` and the data sources `Flow`s that "listen" to the clock for when to emit their data.  In the systems I've built the clock has been more of a `Sink` that triggers the computation of `Flow`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "defined clock".

**Actual Wall Time**

As you mentioned `Source.tick` is one possibility to get a clock of actual times coming from the system clock.  The problem is that the `Sink` may not signal demand at a rate that is greater than or equal to the interval that the Source generates ticks.  For example, your Sink may only signal demand once every minute but your interval in Source.tick may be `10 seconds`.  In this case the 5 intermediate ticks will be dropped, from the documentation:

> If a consumer has not requested any elements at the point in time when
>   the tick element is produced it will not receive that tick element
>   later.

**Simulated Time**

It is always possible to simulate time using a `Source`.

We can first create a function that will simulate a clock using a start time, end time, and interval:

```
type MillisFromEpoch = Long

type MillisInterval = Long


val clock : (MillisFromEpoch, MillisFromEpoch, MillisInterval) => () => Iterator[MillisFromEpoch] = 
  (startTime, stopTime, interval) => () => new Iterator[MillisFromEpoch] {
    var currentTime = startTime

    override def hasNext : Boolean = currentTime < stopTime

    override def next() : MillisFromEpoch = {
      val returnMilis = currentTime
      currentTime += interval

      return returnMillis
    }
  }
```

This clock can now feed a Source.  As an example we can create a  clock that start at [unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) and increments 1 second until the end of time:

```
val epoch : MillisFromEpoch = 0L

val second : MillisInterval = 1000L

val simulatedClockFromEpochSource : Source[MillisFromEpoch,_] = 
  Source fromIterator clock(epoch, Long.MaxValue, 1*second)
```

Or we can create a clock that starts now, and ends in 60 seconds incrementing by 5 second intervals:

```
val now : MillisFromEpoch = System.currentTimeMillis()

val simulatedClockFromNowSource : Source[MillisFromEpoch,_] = 
  Source fromIterator clock(now, now + 60*second, 5*second)
```

**Sampling Frequency**

There is a way to use Source.tick even when the downstream consumer is slower than the tick interval specified at the Source.  We can create a `Flow.filter` that is constantly signaling demand to the Source but will only pass through times that are a defined increment apart.

We can start with a function that does the tracking of the time interval with an internal variable:

```
val frequencySample : (MillisInterval) => (MillisFromEpoch) => Boolean = 
  (interval) => {

    var lastValidTime : MillisFromEpoch = -1

    (timeToCheck) => {
      if(lastValidTime < 0 || timeToCheck >= lastValidTime + interval) {
        lastValidTime = timeToCheck

        true
      }
      else {
        false
      }
    }
  }
```

And now this function can be used to create the Flow:

```
val frequencySampleFlow : (MillisInterval) => Flow[MillisFromEpoch, MillisFromEpoch, _] =
  (frequency) => Flow[MillisFromEpoch]  filter frequencySample(frequency)
```

Now we can create a Flow that has a slow frequency (e.g. 10 seconds) that is attached to a Source with a higher frequency (e.g. 1 second):

```
val slowFrequency : MillisInterval = 10 * second

//simulatedClockFromEpoch ticks every 1 second
//frequnencySampleFlow only passes every 10 second tick through
val slowSource = 
  simulatedClockFromEpochSource via frequencySampleFlow(slowFrequency)
```

Comment: This is a really helpful answer--thank you.  With this mocked clock a historical data source would then listen to the ticks to know when to emit.  Perhaps beyond the scope of this question: I'm additionally wondering how a `Flow` dependent on the source could indicate which data to emit if, for example, it were only dependent on a subset of the data, at a lower frequency than available, or for only a subset of the full history.  Such a `Flow` could simply ignore data that it's not interested in, but it would be inefficient to stream that data if it's not really needed.

Comment: @fwc You are welcome.  I have updated my answer to address the question in your comment.